# This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement. All .so already exists for native java app

Tags: java, android, google-play, native

I'm trying publish my native android app to the store and I'm getting this error

> Error This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit
>   requirement
>
> The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but
>   they only have 32-bit native code: 50.
>
> Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App
>   Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device
>   architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids
>   increasing the overall size of your app.

I already made sure that all x86 armeabi-v7a x86_64 arm64-v8a exist and they have similar .so files

and added this to app gradle file

```
ndk {abiFilters  "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"}
```

here is a screenshot for apk analyzer https://i.ibb.co/BwXp3ZH/Screenshot-from-2019-08-23-04-28-28.png

some .so files were missing from x86_61 and arm64-v8a but I already resolved this and updated my libraries but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. What else can I do to inspect this?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. still looking for the problem. 
I will publish the solution once I reach it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to remove all .so files and the lib directory at all but the problem was still there.

While inspecting my project modules, I found this line inside build.gradle

```
renderscriptTargetApi 20
```

Increasing the target api solved the issue.

References
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference/overview